# React MUI Alert with Styled Button Action

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How do I do a Styled Button in an Alert Action in React MUI? Its not registering or seeing my css changes. Do I need to pass parameter certain way?

**React:**

```
const StyledButton = styled(Button)`
 font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
 padding-bottom: 1px;
 color: '#663C00';
 background-color: 'transparent';
 text-decoration: 'none';
 && {
   font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
   padding-bottom: '1px';
   color: '#663C00';
   background-color: 'transparent';
   text-decoration: 'none';
 }
```

`;

**HTML:**

```
<Alert
   severity="warning"
   action={
   <StyledButton href={getChargeURL()}>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Its not registering or seeing my css

tl;dr - syntax is invalid

You are specifying the css as `CSSProperties` used for *inline* styling, directly in JSX (`CSSProperties` is a dictionary object with `camelCased` keys and strings as value).

You should remove the *quotes* (`'`) from styles, replace *commas* (`,`) with *semicolons* (`;`) and do not *camelCase* it, just like you would do with a standard `css` syntax.

```
const StyledButton = styled(Button)`
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  color: #663C00;
  ...and so on
`;
```

Comment: I made the change on my typo, and still not working, its working elsewhere in the app

Comment: @mattsmith5 I just tested it, applying styles works well. https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-night-mnl7n4?file=/demo.js